# Deleting elements from containers while iterating through them

Tags: c++

Ok, I've run into this issue multiple times and thought it would be nice to throw this out to the good people on SO.

Say I have made a class, lets call it Resource.
So the Resource class has a boolean variable which indicates weather any instance is active or not.

Now, I create a container which holds references to objects of the Resource type.

Over time , some of them  get deactivated and I want to delete these deactivated objects so that they free up memory.
Invariably I try to do this by : trying to iterate over the elements in the container and deleting the ones flagged as inactive. This , obviously leads to problems with iterator invalidation and the program starts throwing runtime errors.

So finally, my question is , what is the best method to safely delete objects depending on some condition that can only be evaluated by looking into the contents of the object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [deleting while iterating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901356/deleting-while-iterating)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iterate vector, remove certain items as I go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604588/iterate-vector-remove-certain-items-as-i-go)

Comment: Not talking about just vectors or lists, also maps and other associative containers.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) with [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). E.g.:

```
std::vector<int> myvec;
...
myvec.erase(std::remove_if(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(), [] (int i) -> bool { return false; }), myvec.end());
```

Comment: What about associative containers like maps ? std::remove_if doesnt work for them I gather.

Comment: @angryInsomniac: no it doesn't work because it would break ordering. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515357/map-lambda-remove-if) provides an answer for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The safest method is to use `std::remove_if`. This will move all items that match the given predicate to the end of the sequence. You can then delete them.

Comment: What about associative containers like maps ?

Comment: With a map you can delete the element an iterator points to without invalidating any other iterators. That means you can do `your_map.erase(it++);`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/) for more information.