# why std::for_each with deletion of elements not break iteration?

Tags: c++, c++11

As far as I know, erasing elements during iteration of a collection should break the iteration or cause you to skip elements. Why does calling std::for_each with a predicate which erases not cause this to happen? (It works).

Code snip:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<int,long long> m;
    m[1] = 5000;
    m[2] = 1;
    m[3] = 2;
    m[4] = 5000;
    m[5] = 5000;
    m[6] = 3;

    // Erase all elements > 1000
    std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), [&](const decltype(m)::value_type& v){
        if (v.second > 1000) {
            m.erase(v.first);
        }
    });

    for (const auto& a: m) {
      cout << a.second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it prints out

```
1
2
3
```

EDIT: I now see that ***if*** it actually increments the iterator before calling the function then it could work. But does this count as compiler specific/undefined behavior?

Comment: If you're actually doing this, I suggest `std::remove_if`.

Comment: That won't work for associative containers (like map) :(

Remove_if returns an iterator for a position to start deleting from (it moves all the ones to be removed to the back of the collection)

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at. My bad.

Comment: Yea, more info here on that specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515357/map-lambda-remove-if

Comment: About your actual question, I would say it's implementation-defined and not guaranteed. There aren't any specific points for or against it from what I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour, and won't work reliably.  After adding a line to print keys and values inside your erasing lambda function, I see:

```
1=5000
2=1
3=2
4=5000
2=1          // AGAIN!!!
3=2          // AGAIN!!!
5=5000
6=3
```

With my Standard library's `map` implementation, after erasing the element with key 4, iteration returns to the node with key 2!  It then revisits the node with key `3`.  Because your lambda happily retested such nodes (`v.second > 1000`) and returned without any side effects, the broken iteration wasn't affecting the output.

You might reasonably ask: "but isn't it astronomically unlikely that it'd have managed to continue iteration (even if to the wrong next node) without crashing?"

Actually, it's quite likely.

Erasing a node causes `delete` to be called for the memory that node occupied, but in general the library code performing the `delete` will just:

- invoke the destructor (which has no particular reason to waste time overwriting the left-child-, right-child- and parent-pointers), then
- modify its records of which memory regions are allocated vs. available.

It's unlikely to "waste" time arbitrarily modifying the heap memory being deallocated (though some implementations will in memory-usage debugging modes).

So, the erased node *probably* sits there intact until some other heap allocation's performed.

And, when you `erase` an element in a `map`, the Standard requires that none of the container's other elements be moved in memory - iterators, pointers and references to other elements *must* remain valid.  It can only modify nodes' left/right/parent pointers that maintain the binary tree.

Consequently, if you continue to use the iterator to the erased element, it is likely to see pointers to the left/right/parent nodes the erased element linked to before erasure, and `operator++()` will "iterate" to them using the same logic it would have employed if the erased element were still in the `map`.

If we consider an example map's internal binary tree, where N3 is a node with key 3:

```
                           N5
                          /  \
                        N3    N7
                       / \    /
                      N1  N4 N6
```

The way iteration is done will likely be:

- initially, start at the N1; the `map` must directly track where this is to ensure `begin()` is O(1)
- if on a node with no children, repeat { Nfrom = where you are, move to parent, if nullptr or right != Nfrom break} (e.g. N1->N3, N4->N3->N5, N6->N7->N5->nullptr)
- if on a node with right-hand child, take it then any number of left-hand links (e.g. N3->N4, N5->N7->N6)

So, if say N4 is removed (so `N3->right = nullptr;`) and no rebalancing occurs, then iteration records NFrom=N4 then moves to the parent N3, then N3->right != Nfrom, so it will think it should stop on the already-iterated-over N3 instead of moving on up to N5.

On the other hand, if the tree has been rebalanced after the `erase`, all bets are off and the invalidated iterator could repeat or skip elements or even iterate "as hoped".

This is *not* intended to let you reason about behaviour after an `erase` - it's undefined and shouldn't be relied on.  Rather, I'm just showing that a sane implementation can account for your unexpected observations.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to work for you, but I wouldn't count on it -- it's likely undefined behavior.

Specifically, I'd be concerned that erasing a map element while running `std::for_each` would attempt to increment an invalid iterator. For example, it looks like [`libc++` implements `std::for_each`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01499_source.html) like so:

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Function>
_Function 
for_each(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Function __f) {
   // concept requirements
   __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator>)
     __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);
   for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
     __f(*__first);
   return _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__f);
 }
```

If calling `__f` ends up performing an erase, it seems likely that `__first` would be invalidated. Attempting to subsequently increment an invalid iterator would then be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`std::for_each` is defined in the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (25.2.4) as a non-modifying sequence operation. The fact that modifying the sequence using your implementation of the function works is probably just luck.

This is definitely implementation-defined, and you shouldn't be doing it. The standard expects that you *don't* modify the container inside the function object.

Answer (score 0):

I find this operation pretty common, so to avoid the undefined behaviour above, I wrote a container based algorithm.

```
void remove_erase_if( Container&&, Test&& );
```

to deal with both associative and not containers, I tag dispatch on a custom trait class `is_associative_container` -- the associative goes to a manual while loop, while the others go to a `remove_if`-`erase` version.

In my case I just hard code the 4 associative containers in the trait -- you could duck type it, bit it is a higher level concept, so you would be just pattern matching anyhow.

Comment: `remove_erase_if( Container&&, Test&& );` - why would you take the container by `&&`?

Comment: @tonyd perfect forwarding style allowing both const and non const arguments.

Comment: yes, I appreciate what it can do - question was why.  C++ disallowed binding a normal reference to a temporary because it's generally considered to be more likely to introduce bugs when done accidentally than be useful, and in this case modifying a temporary container has few potential uses.

Comment: @TonyD and if `remove_erase_if` returned `Container`?  My actual version doesn't return `void`.

Comment: and there we have enough information for readers to see what you've done and why, then they can decide whether they'd rather a const reference or to rely on moves... all good.  Cheers.