# Lambda issue in std::find

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, find, stdmap

I have a map as follows:

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Person>> ratingMap;
```

I want to create a function that takes a string argument _name and iterates through the map until it finds a person with the same name:

```
void Person::deleteFromMap(const std::string& _name){
    //Searches the map for a person whose name is the same as the argument _name
    auto found = std::find(ratingMap.begin(), ratingMap.end(),
        [&](const std::unique_ptr<Person>& person) -> bool{return person->getName() == _name; });
```

However, this refuses to compile and gives the following error:

Error   1   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::pair' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I've spent close to two hours trying variations of this in an attempt to get it to work, because I've written similar lambda functions in the past like this that have compiled and worked as expected. Why is this happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [map, lambda, remove\_if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515357/map-lambda-remove-if)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you must use [`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if) **not** [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find), and fix the argument type of your lambda.

```
auto found = std::find_if(ratingMap.begin(), ratingMap.end(),
//                    ^^^
    [&](const std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<Person>>& person) -> bool
       { return person.second->getName() == _name; });
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it. I was initially using find_if with my original code and thought that I was mistaken in doing so, turns out the argument type was the culprit from the start.

Answer (score 8):

It should be

```
void Person::deleteFromMap(const std::string& _name){
    //Searches the map for a person whose name is the same as the argument _name
    auto found = std::find_if(ratingMap.begin(), ratingMap.end(),
        [&](std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<Person>>& p) -> bool{return p.second->getName() == _name; });
```

as `map::value_type` is `std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<Person>>`.

**EDIT**: And as noted by other, it is `std::find_if` which takes the predicate.

Comment: I've edited my code and it is exactly as so, yet I am still getting the same thing: error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: @Bluejay: Fixed. I didn't see the second error in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Underlying iterator type for your map is not `std::unique_ptr<Person>`. but `std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<Person>>`.

You need to modify your lambda to take correct argument

```
[&](const std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<Person>>& pair)
```

and extract second value from the pair in comparison

```
return pair.second->getName() == _name;
```

You should also use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) As it accepts UnaryPredicate instead of just value